# Gaussian Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

1. Why does the area under a normally distributed curve give us a probability? For example, why does $P(Z\leq a)$ equal the area under the curve to the left of $a$?
2. The standard normal distribution has equation $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} $. Suppose we wanted to find the $P(Z=1)$, could we not just find $f(1)$ which would equal $P(Z=1)$?

   3. I'm used to thinking of $Z$ as the 'Z-Score' which describes the number of standard deviations a value in any data set is from the mean. Would it be best to think of $Z$ in the context of another data set with parameters $(\mu=0,\sigma=1)$ which can be mapped to from any data set $X$ using the formula $\displaystyle Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ when dealing with the normal distribution?

Comment: How much do you understand about probability distributions in general - Cumulative distributions etc? Is this a problem with just the normal dist.  or more generally.

Comment: @Chinny84 Just started statistics yesterday, so this is the first probability distribution I've been exposed to. Just the normal distribution

Comment: This is a very broad question without setting the basics. But I tried to answer the questions you have as simply as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic property of probability distributions is the fact that we have a concept of a cumulative distribution. This is a function that gives us the probability of at least this event happening - An example is what is the probability of at most a value of $3$ appearing this is equivalent to
$$
P(X < 4)
$$
This is essentially
$$
P(X=1) + P(X=2) + P(X=3) = P(X\leq 3)
$$
or the sum of all the values of $X$ up until $X=3$, or better still the sum of all the points left of $a=3$. We use $a$ as we can have any value of $a$ as long as it is contained in the valid domain of probability.
We write the cumulative distribution as 
$$
P(X\leq a) = \sum_{k=\text{low limit}}^a P(X=k)
$$
or for a continuous distribution, like the normal we want the integral
$$
P(X\leq a) = \int_{\text{low limit}}^a f(x)dx
$$
(note low limit is $-\infty$ for the normal dist.)

For number 2. A continuous distribution has the property that a probability at any given point is always zero, it is intuitive when you understand what a probability is. In any case this is zero, so you can not simply input a value of $x$ and map this to a probability. We deal with probability that we are within a range i.e $P(a < x < b)$ is a valid argument.

Number 3. No, a normal distribution is simple taking the `Z-score` of a Gaussian. So the normal distribution is the scaled distribution of the Gaussian - Where the Gaussian is given by have $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You should think a gaussian distribution as a function which, given a sample and a value, returns the probability of that value to be choosen randomly in that sample. Its form is a bell because the probability decays as the value becomes far from the mean.

1) It is important to note that the area below the curve in a parameter interval is not the probability of a specific value but the sum of probabilities of all values in that range instead. This is why the area of the normalized gaussian is equal to 1 and why the probability of any values less than `a` is equal to the area left of `a`. If you aren't familiar with integrals, you should read about it to understand how areas below functions can be seen as sums of functions in tiny intervals.

2) The parameter to the gaussian is not the probability, but the value in the sample.

3) Try to see gaussian in the way described in this answer and you should have a better overall idea of what a gaussian is.